# CORS policy blocked access from production server

Tags: nginx, cors, private-network-access

I'm working on a mern app and it works fine on the local sver with app.use(cors()) in the server.js file but on the production server I get a cors error.  Right now I just have the ip address for the server so I tried addint it to the options but I still get the error.

When I use:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://myipaddress',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
app.use(cors());
```

It doesn't work on the localhost either so I got it working there with :

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://173.255.205.85',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
} else {
  app.use(cors());
}
```

With that it works on the localhost but not on the server.

I don't really get cors and how it works but if I take it out completely it doesn't work on either localhost or the server.

Not sure if it matters but the production server is nginx runing on ubuntu.

The actual error I get in the console is:

```
cess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://ipaddress' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address s
```

If I create an actual domain for the server and add it to the list will that fix the problem?  Is the ip address the issue?

Comment: Is the origin in the error message the same origin in your corsOptions (myipaddress vs ipaddress)? If this is the production server then why is it trying to access something on localhost, or did you take the error message from your development setup?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the issue wasn't in the server it was in the request.  On the localhost I am requestiong with:

```
const { data } = await AuthApi.logIn(formData);
```

Which calls in the file that has a base url of 'http://localhost:3000 and sets up the request.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000' });
export const logIn = (formData) => API.post('/api/auth/login', formData);
export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/api/auth/register', formData);
```

I realized that for the server I just need to change the initiall call and not call this file at all.

```
const API_URL = '/api/auth/';

const { data } = await axios.post(API_URL + 'login', formData);
```

Now it works.